# Monte Carlo Simulation of Charged Particles in Non-Uniform Electric Field

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, probability-or-statistics, finite-element-method, physics

I have a code (provided below) which simulates the motion of an ensemble of charged particles which are subjected to a complex static electric field which passes through some aperture in a metallic surface (N spheres, whose number is defined as `numbodies` in my code).

Now, I would like to run the simulation for a single particle many, many times, and plot each of their final resting places on the surface (`z=-partRad`) of my metalized aperture at `(x(tfin), y(tfin), z= -partRad)` together, in 2D. These coordinates can be displayed as simple dots in the x-y plane.

It would also be cool to superimpose the surface of my aperture onto the x-y graph of the final particle locations, to see exactly where they most frequently land. I would also like to find the average distance these particles center from some user specified point(s), after everything is said and done. I would also appreciate any cool ideas for statistical analysis regarding the outcome of the Monte Carlo simulation!!!

Each of the particles should be given a random starting position and velocity given by

```
vel0 = Table[
  Partition[{RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}], 
    RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}], RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}]}, 1],
   numbodies]
pos0 = Table[
   Partition[{RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{-0.4, -0.04}]}, 1], numbodies];
```

in my code.

The first part of the code, above the `(***... MONTE CARLO CAN START...***)` line in my code, doesn't need to be included in the Monte Carlo simulation (unless you find some reason I do not see).

Here is the code. Happy hunting!

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

q = 1.617733*10^-18;(*Net ion Charge*)

R = Import[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dds8rm3odg2m7gu/largeAp.obj?dl=1"];
RegionDimension[R];
M = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2]];
RegionDimension[M];
Volume[M];

r = RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[
    RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, 0.5}], M], 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.4}, {2, 2, 0.5}]], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, -6.4}]];
ToElementMesh[r]["Wireframe"];
pol = -1;

V0 = 1000;

sol = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == -pol*
       V0/2, (0.4 <= z <= 0.5) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      pol*V0/2, (0.0071 <= z <= 0.0072) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <=
         2)], DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (0 <= z <= 0.0070) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (-6.5 <= z <= -6.4) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)]}, 
   V, {x, y, z} \[Element] r];

electricField[x_, y_, z_] = -Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];

v = Show[VectorPlot3D[
    electricField[x, y, z], {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 1}, {z, -0.5, 0.1}, 
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorScale -> 0.05, 
    VectorPoints -> 7, PlotLegends -> Automatic], M];

mass = 6.52*10^-11;(*particle mass in kg/m^3*)

eforceX[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[1]];
eforceY[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[2]];
eforceZ[x_, y_, z_] = q*Grad[sol[x, y, z], {x, y, z}][[3]];

(***********************    MONTE CARLO CAN START    ******************************)

numbodies = 1;

vel0 = Table[
  Partition[{RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}], 
    RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}], RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}]}, 1],
   numbodies]
pos0 = Table[
   Partition[{RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
     RandomReal[{-0.4, -0.04}]}, 1], numbodies];

tfin = 1000;

eqs = Table[{x1[j]''[t] == -a[t]*(1/mass)*eforceX[x, y, z] /. {x -> 
       x1[j][t], y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]}, 
    y1[j]''[t] == -a[t]*(1/mass)*eforceY[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]}, 
    z1[j]''[t] == -a[t]*(1/mass)*eforceZ[x, y, z] /. {x -> x1[j][t], 
      y -> y1[j][t], z -> z1[j][t]}, x1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 1, 1]], 
    y1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 2, 1]], z1[j][0] == pos0[[j, 3, 1]], 
    x1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 1, 1]], y1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 2, 1]], 
    z1[j]'[0] == vel0[[j, 3, 1]], a[0] == 1}, {j, numbodies}];

partRad = 0.0125;

vars = Flatten[Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]}, {j, numbodies}]];

event = Table[
   WhenEvent[
     z1[j][t] >= -partRad, {a[t] -> 0, x1[j]'[t] -> 0, y1[j]'[t] -> 0,
       z1[j]'[t] -> 0}] /. {j -> i}, {i, numbodies}];

sol1 = NDSolve[{eqs, event}, Head /@ vars, {t, 0, tfin}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> a]


frames = Table[
   Show[v, ParametricPlot3D[
     Table[{x1[j][t], y1[j][t], z1[j][t]} /. sol1, {j, 
       numbodies}], {t, 0, tf}, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> Off], 
    Graphics3D[
     Table[{Hue[.35], 
       Sphere[{x1[j][tf], y1[j][tf], z1[j][tf]} /. sol1, 0.025]}, {j, 
       numbodies}]]], {tf, .015*tfin, tfin, .015*tfin}];

ListAnimate[Rasterize[#, "Image"] & /@ frames]
```

Comment: Hi @DanielHuber. Are you running into a problem trying to execute the code? I copy/pasted the exact code provided above, and it runs without error on my end.

Comment: Sorry, I must have done something wrong by copy/past. There was a Table command without iterator.

Comment: @zak720 As I remember we have discussed once this mesh with two holes on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269806/defining-dirichlet-boundary-conditions-on-an-imported-3d-object-with-apertures-i/269867#269867

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To simulate hundreds and thousands runs we need very fast code, while at present form code for trajectories is very slow. To improve code, first, we include the electric field computation in `NDSolve` as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

q = 1.617733*10^-18;(*Net ion Charge*)

R = Import[
   "https://www.dropbox.com/s/dds8rm3odg2m7gu/largeAp.obj?dl=1"];
RegionDimension[R];
M = BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[R], MeshCells[R, 2]];
r = RegionDifference[
   RegionDifference[
    RegionDifference[Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, 0.5}], M], 
    Cuboid[{0, 0, 0.4}, {2, 2, 0.5}]], 
   Cuboid[{0, 0, -6.5}, {2, 2, -6.4}]];
pol = -1;

V0 = 1000;

{U, {Fx, Fy, Fz}} = 
  NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == -pol*
       V0/2, (0.4 <= z <= 0.5) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      pol*V0/2, (0.0071 <= z <= 0.0072) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <=
         2)], DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (0 <= z <= 0.0070) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 2)], 
    DirichletCondition[
     V[x, y, z] == 
      0, (-6.5 <= z <= -6.4) && (0 <= y <= 2) && (0 <= x <= 
        2)]}, {V, -Grad[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}]}, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
    r];
```

Visualization

```
v = Show[
  VectorPlot3D[{Fx, Fy, Fz}, {x, 0.5, 1}, {y, 0.5, 1}, {z, -0.5, 0.1},
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", VectorScale -> 0.05, 
   VectorPoints -> 7, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
  RegionPlot3D[R, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Second, we use [Verlet integration algorithm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208590/numerically-solving-a-system-of-many-coupled-non-linear-odes-efficiently) to simulate trajectories, we have

```
mass = 6.52*10^-11;(*particle mass*)
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 100; X0 = Take[RandomReal[{.5, 1}, 2 n], n]; Y0 = 
 Take[RandomReal[{.5, 1}, 2 n], -n]; Z0 = 
 RandomReal[{-.4, -.04}, n]; rrv = 
 RandomReal[{-0.0001, 0.0001}, 3 n]; u0 = Take[rrv, n]; v0 = 
 Take[rrv, {n + 1, 2 n}]; w0 = Take[rrv, -n];


SymplecticLeapfrog = {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta", 
  "DifferenceOrder" -> 2, "PositionVariables" :> qvars}; time = {t, 0,
   2}; tm = 10^3; partRad = 0.0125; qvars = {X[t], Y[t], Z[t]};
eqn[i_] := {X''[t] == q/mass tm^2 Fx /. {x -> X[t], y -> Y[t], 
    z -> Z[t]}, 
  Y''[t] == q/mass tm^2 Fy /. {x -> X[t], y -> Y[t], z -> Z[t]}, 
  Z''[t] == q/mass tm^2 Fz /. {x -> X[t], y -> Y[t], z -> Z[t]}, 
  X[0] == X0[[i]], Y[0] == Y0[[i]], Z[0] == Z0[[i]], X'[0] == u0[[i]],
   Y'[0] == v0[[i]], Z'[0] == w0[[i]], 
  WhenEvent[Z[t] >= -partRad, end = t; "StopIntegration"]}; h = 10^-4;
 Do[soln[i] = 
   NDSolve[eqn[i], qvars, time, StartingStepSize -> h, 
    Method -> SymplecticLeapfrog]; 
  T[i] = end;, {i, 1, n}]
```

It takes about 25 sec to compute 100 trajectories on my laptop. Visualization of trajectories

```
Show[v, Table[
  ParametricPlot3D[qvars /. soln[i], {t, 0, T[i]}, 
   ColorFunction -> Hue], {i, 100}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Finally we can compute point distribution as

```
fin = Table[qvars /. soln[i][[1]] /. t -> T[i], {i, n}];
Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, Point[fin]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{.5, 1}, {.5, 1}, All}], 
 RegionPlot3D[R, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]]
```

[image: Figure 3]

To compute statistics we need 10^4 points as minimum. Example with 1000 points
[image: Figure 4]

Example with $10^4$ points
[image: Figure 5]

In the last case 33 particles of 10000 are not deposited on the plane `z==-partRad`, therefore we select cases and plot as follows

```
fin = Table[qvars /. soln[i][[1]] /. t -> T[i], {i, n}];

fin1 = Select[fin, Norm[#[[3]] + partRad] <= .01 &];

Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, Point[fin1]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{.5, 1}, {.5, 1}, All}], 
 RegionPlot3D[R, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]]
```

Using `fin1` we can compute mean and standard deviation on every coordinate

```
XYmean = Mean[fin1]

(*Out[]= {0.757097, 0.754464, -0.0125015}*)

 std = StandardDeviation[fin1]

(*Out[]= {0.0511615, 0.045477, 0.000108942}*)
```

Visualization of mean and `std[[1]]` as a sphere

```
Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, Point[fin1]}, {Blue, Opacity[0.25], 
    Sphere[XYmean, std[[1]]]}}, PlotRange -> {{.5, 1}, {.5, 1}, All}, 
  Axes -> {True, True, False}], 
 RegionPlot3D[R, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]]
```

[image: Figure 6]

Comment: this is an absolute work of art. I had come up with a very crude version of this prior to seeing this answer (and it is, as you might guess, extremely slow). Fantastic work.

Comment: How would I set a WhenEvent such that when a particle comes into contact with any other particle position previously simulated, its motion comes to a stop? In my crude version, I made an empty list called `outCoord`  and filled it with the final resting coordinates of each particle simulated. I then check whether, `WhenEvent[
 Sqrt[(outCoord[[k, 1]][[1, 1]] - 
       x1[j][t])^2 + (outCoord[[k, 1]][[1, 2]] - 
       y1[j][t])^2 + (outCoord[[k, 1]][[1, 3]] - z1[j][t])^2] <= 
  partRad` for each new particle simulated, such that if this is true, it stops. How can I do it here?

Comment: I don't understand last question. Do you mean collisions or something else?

Comment: Yes like a collision. If a particle encounters a region of space where previously simulated particles have landed, it's motion stops. This would create a 3D structure of particles on the surface since they would now be able to "stack" on top of eachother.

Comment: Ok, for this we need to define some size of particle and rule  for packaging.

Comment: One could make the particle radius `Rp = 0.01`. Then if the center of a simulated particle comes within `2 Rp` of the final positions of any other previously simulated particles, integration would stop. Efficiently implementing such a condition is paramount, as I suspect this could balloon into an extremely expensive task if done improperly.

Comment: @Zach Yes, we can solve this problem in several steps. On the first step we simulate portion of particles with `WhenEvent[Z[t] >= -partRad, end = t; "StopIntegration"]` with portion of 10^4, and on the second step we update `partRad` using some packaging criterium, then repeat. But may be we need some averaged model with continues `z=-partRad[x ,y ,t]` and ion density.

Comment: this sounds like a very interesting approach. What is meant by "packaging criterium"? How would you implement such an idea?

Comment: It depends on how ions interact in a solid state, what lattice and compounds could be in this system. For instance there is a cubic lattice, then we need to know what period of this lattice.

Comment: in such lattices we could define a period for x,y,z such that when a new particle comes within some distance of an ion it has to fill the potential lattice sight that is defined by the period of the defined unit cell, closest in proximity.

Comment: a simple lattice period could be `\[Beta] partRad` in x,y,z, where `\[Beta]` could be just some number that could be changed per application

Comment: For numerical application it could be better just to give a number for betta.

Comment: Could one make a cube centered at each particle's final location, such that each cube created becomes a part of the same object? The object would get updated after each run, where, if a newly simulated particle comes into contact with the object comprised of the many cubes, the final resting point of the particle will be the nearest of the vertices of the greater cubic object?